# Reference books for Foundation of Mathematics (Logic and Philosophy)

Tags: logic, reference-request, proof-writing, foundations, philosophy

I am an undergraduate student. And I want to build solid foundation for Mathematics.
I tried google search but could not get proper recommendation.
Please suggest books which covers the subject nicely.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Lang's Basic Mathematics

Comment: Do you have any other suggestion

Comment: More than one suggestion isn't a problem

Comment: I could give you other suggestions, but that's the best starting point imo for most math.

Comment: For Basic logic I'll suggest “Book of Proof” by Richard Hammack.

Comment: Ok thank you to you both. I'll have a look

Comment: I was going to suggest van Dalen's "Logic and Structure" which is an undergrad logic textbook, but if you're just trying to get a solid foundation to do "actual math" (rather than specializing in logic), that might not be the most useful for you.

Comment: I read and enjoyed "How to prove it" by Daniel Velleman as a sophomore

Comment: A once fairly standard text for the foundations of mathematics at the advanced (U.S.) undergraduate level is [**Introduction to the Foundations of Mathematics**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486488209) by Raymond Louis Wilder (1965 2nd edition, reprinted by Dover Publications in 2012).

Comment: Ok. Thank you all for helping.it'll help me a lot to choose.